# Instagram Acceptable API Usage

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We're new to developing for Instagram and after a thorough read of Instagram's developer policy and API guidelines, I'll admit to some level of confusion with what we are and are not allowed to do. Our application is a custom-built-for-a-specific-brand loyalty platform that rewards customers and allows them to progress in points/tiers to higher levels for things like discounts at the brand, reward certificates, special brand experiences, etc.

As I don't have a direct way to ask Instagram, here are our questions:

- We want to scan the public timeline and look for certain tags + get the userID of the account that used the tag
- We want to be able to let a user give us their Instagram username, authenticate with Instagram, and then give them some bonus points for doing so
- We want to be able to give bonus points to customers who have given us their usernames, authenticated, and then posted using a certain hashtag
- Would Instagram consider a loyalty platform that a customer has opted-in to to be an acceptable use of the API?

It looks like access to the public_content and likes scopes in Instagram was cutoff on October 1, 2017 and they are not accepting new submissions. We can still get access to the basic scope, but I think the items that would help us the most are in the now-defunct calls.

Any thoughts on the above?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questions is a legal one and not a programming one. You should consult a lawyer, not a bunch of strangers on the Internet.

Comment: This is not a legal question. a. Instagram suggests posting API-related questions to this community on their developer support pages. b. People that have written applications are hanging around here and will have a far broader range of experiences in working with Instagram and can speak to what they've had success with. c. The changes to Instagram API policies are unclear and might be more easily explained by someone who has recently gone through that process...